# the II chord followed by the IV chord in a major key?

Tags: chords, chord-progressions, transition

I am analyzing the music of [Name of Life arranged by Makiko HIroHashi] (https://musescore.com/user/4622501/scores/5038709).

From measure 29 - 30 it goes from :

(First half Measure 29 ): Eb minor [ii]
(second half Measure 29): Eb major [II]
(Measure 30): Gb major [IV]

I was wondering why does the II -> IV work? Is it some type of augmented6th chord, secondary dominant, or enharmonic progression that I am not seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the score you provide I see Eb9 in measure 29 (highlighted in red), notes Eb-**G**-Bb-Db-F (there is no Gb, so no Ebm), and Gb/Ab in measure 30, which can be interpreted as Absus. Bbm follows in measure 31.

Eb9 is a dominant chord; it is a *secondary dominant* to Absus, which is a dominant chord in the key of Db. It then resolves *deceptively* to Bbm, vi chord in the key of Db.

[image]